# Laravel package register exception handler

Tags: php, laravel-5, service-provider

I wonder if it's possible to register a second Exception Handler in a package in Laravel 5.

I have a package (let's call it **api-serializer**) that register a middleware to convert all requests to JSON (for an API) and this package register 2 helpers: `success()` and `failure()` that handle specifically the json when an error occurs (or not).

In my application exception handler I do the following:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    return failure($e->getMessage());
}
```

Now I have a second package (let's call it **tumblr-api**) that makes http calls and raise exceptions, for instance:

```
throw (new CustomCoolException)->setModel($model);
```

I would like to treat this exception differently, because the message is located in the `$model`, do smething like this:

```
if ($e instanceof CustomCoolException) {
    return failure($e->getModel()->getMessage());
}
```

What **I don't want to do** it's to add my package exception to my main exception handler, as they'll be tightly binded.

I neither want to create a dependency between my *api-serializer* that exposes `success()` and `failure()` to my *tumblr-api* package.

Is it possible, from my **api-serializer** to register a second ExceptionHandler or add specific switchs for it's exceptions without altering anything else ?

I would like to make my *tumblr-api* package as independent as possible, so the user installing it just have to register the service provider and go !

Answer (score 5):

You can override the App's Exception handler with your own package's exception handler in your package's controllers like this:

```
class YourPackageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        \App::singleton(
            \Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
            YourExceptionHandler::class
        );
    }
```

Credits go to malhal at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/custom-exception-handler-based-on-route-group